# JAVA Mail - username, password, host

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have following code

```
private void emailFile(){
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "destinationemail@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "fromemail@gmail.com";

        final String username = "manishaspatil";//change accordingly
        final String password = "******";//change accordingly

        // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
        String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    .....
}
```

I want to know that what is `username`, `password` (is it the same as of my email password or what?), `host` and the difference between ( `host`, `username` and `from` ).

Comment: yes it's same as your username and password

Comment: then what's the difference between `username` and `from` ?

Comment: from is `youremail@gmail.com` username  `youremail` or full mail address

Comment: so in other words `from` can be same as `username`. like I have email address like `junaid@yahoo.com`, so `from = junaid@yahoo.com` and `username = junaid@yahoo.com` and the password will be the password of `junaid@yahoo.com` account. Right ?

Comment: yes but your username can be junaid without @yahoo but from should be mail address. from cannot be  junaid it should have `@id` .username and mail address is different

Comment: Thanks ... and what about `host`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66349/discussion-between-junaid-and-fast-snail).